# collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize returning wrong value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I subclassed `UICollectionView` class and adjusted the height of the collection view. I used this code:

```
- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize{
    return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;
}
```

But it always returns the wrong height for the content size. I tried logging the frame values after which I found that it was returning the height of frame rather than that of content.

[image]

In this case, content size is : (296, 188).
              frame size is.  : (296, 174).

Please let me know what I am missing, thanks.

Comment: you can use sizeForItemAtIndexPath method of collection view to adjust cell size.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CGFloat height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
self.view.setNeedsLayout() Or self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Yes, I am already calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after I reload the collection view but it was of no help.